# Who can explain me better 'the condition with no weight'?

Tags: gravity, weight

This is related to gravity and vaccuum, which says that when the body is in vaccuum, its weight is lost. I need any examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weightlessness for astronauts](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56620/weightlessness-for-astronauts)

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close on the grounds of being unclear as to what is being asked. It's quite clear what is being asked, and what is being asked is a duplicate of many existing questions on weightlessness.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to vacuum, the statement just tells you that far away from big masses like the Earth there is no gravity acting on a body. In this case the gravitational field $\vec g=0$ and therefore $\vec F_g=m\vec g=0$.

Comment: This answer misses the point. Astronauts and cosmonauts on the International Space Station are in a near weightless state, yet the gravitational force is about 88% of standard gravity at that altitude.

Comment: In this case see a different answer of mine: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109636/