# What kind of energy/force do astronauts experience away from the earth 's atmosphere/beyond?

Tags: forces, energy

I have been reading articles and watching space exploration documentaries,as astronauts stay on earth before launching into space,there's gravitational pull or force that acts upon them and the shuttle.

On the other side,after launching off into space and leaving the earth's gravitational waves;there's unknowingly certain energy or force that exists.

Therefore,I'm intrigued to know whether still gravitational waves/force acts again beyond the earth?

And if there's a force/energy that exists,what is the scientific term for it?

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3076/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26332/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic, The OP seems to be asking whether there's gravity in outer space, not about effects on the human body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weightlessness for astronauts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56620/)

Answer (score 2):

to put it simply, although the force of gravity diminishes with distance from the earth, that force has infinite range. astronauts and rockets in space haven't "escaped" gravity, they just don't experience their **weight** because they are on trajectories in which they are freely falling.

regarding other forces in space, those astronauts and rockets experience radiation and high-energy particle beams from the sun which would otherwise be blocked by the earth's atmosphere and radiation from the radiation belts which encircle the earth.

Comment: Thanks for such insightful answer,however you have intrigued me to know more about astronaut and rockets falling freely,which means there's no force acts upon them as long as they are distant away from the gravitational pull(probably away from earth)

Comment: you will find lots of useful info about this here, or on wikipedia! best of luck to you.